# Ruby publish/subscribe implementation issue

Tags: ruby, multithreading, observable

I'm experimenting with [Observable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html) Ruby class that should be capable to provide Publish/Subscribe pattern.

I wrote this code to test the behavior:

```
require "observer"

class Ticker          ### Periodically fetch a stock price.
  include Observable
  attr_accessor :sleep_time

  def initialize(symbol, sleep_time)
    @symbol = symbol
    @sleep_time = sleep_time
  end

  def run
    last_price = nil
    loop do
      price = Price.fetch(@symbol)
      print "#{@symbol}, Current price: #{price}\n"
      if price != last_price
        changed                 # notify observers
        last_price = price
        notify_observers(price)
      end
      sleep @sleep_time
    end
  end
end

class Price           ### A mock class to fetch a stock price (60 - 140).
  def self.fetch(symbol)
    60 + rand(80)
  end
end

class Notification
  attr_accessor :name, :sleep_time
  def initialize(ticker, name, sleep_time)
    @name = name
    @sleep_time = sleep_time
    ticker.add_observer(self)
  end

  def update(price)
    puts @name + ': ' + price.to_s
    sleep @sleep_time
  end
end

ticker = Ticker.new("MSFT", 0.5)
t1 = Thread.new { slow_notification = Notification.new(ticker, 'thread 1', 0) }
t2 = Thread.new { fast_notification = Notification.new(ticker, 'thread 2', 5) }
ticker.run
```

I was expecting that *fast_notification* sent the notification faster than *slow_notification* cause the sleep time for the first is one is 0 seconds and for the other one 5 seconds. In practice, they run at the same time (every 5 seconds).

Comment: Why is this pub/sub related? `notify_observers` implies that the "observer" has direct knowledge of the clients, precluding a pub/sub design / approach to the observing implementation.

Comment: you don't sleep until after your puts statement in `update`

Comment: @Myst that's how the ruby docs explain it as well -> https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html

Comment: @Anthony , Yap, you're right. The observable might be implemented using pub/sub design (though that's debatable), but that's not really my question. My question is "should the pub/sub tag be used? is the pub/sub design part of the question?"

Comment: @Anthony I expect that the print statement in `Ticker` class get executed every 0.5 seconds (main thread) but It get trapped by the other thread.

Comment: @Anthony you are right about the tag. I removed it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa I have 3 threads. The main thread is over a loop and should print the Price of the stock every 0.5 seconds. The others threads should print the price every time the event was sent. I set a sleep time over the Notifications threads so they should have a delay. I wonder why the main thread get trapped by the sleep that I set for the Notifications threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle it in an async way, the thread creation should be within the main loop. I got the expected behavior with these changes:

```
require "observer"

class Ticker          ### Periodically fetch a stock price.
  include Observable
  attr_accessor :sleep_time

  def initialize(symbol, sleep_time)
    @symbol = symbol
    @sleep_time = sleep_time
  end

  def run
    last_price = nil
    loop do
      price = Price.fetch(@symbol)
      #print "#{@symbol}, Current price: #{price}\n"
      if price != last_price
        changed                 # notify observers
        last_price = price
        Thread.new { notify_observers(price, Time.now) }
      end
      sleep @sleep_time
    end
  end
end

class Price           ### A mock class to fetch a stock price (60 - 140).
  def self.fetch(symbol)
    7600 + rand(800)
  end
end

class Notification
  attr_accessor :name, :sleep_time, :working, :mutex, :counter
  def initialize(ticker, name, sleep_time)
    @name = name
    @sleep_time = sleep_time
    @working = false
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    @counter = 0
    ticker.add_observer(self)
  end

  def do_something(price)
    puts @name + ': ' + price.to_s
    sleep @sleep_time
  end

  def update(price, time)
    @mutex.synchronize{
      do_something(price)
    }
  end
end

ticker = Ticker.new("MSFT", 0.5)
Notification.new(ticker, 'Fast notification', 0)
Notification.new(ticker, 'Slow notification', 5)
ticker.run
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should flush the buffer. Try add `STDOUT.flush` after print.

```
  def run
    last_price = nil
    loop do
      price = Price.fetch(@symbol)
      print "#{@symbol}, Current price: #{price}\n"
      STDOUT.flush
      if price != last_price
        changed                 # notify observers
        last_price = price
        notify_observers(price)
      end
      sleep @sleep_time
    end
  end
```